# LiveAuthClient.InitializeAsync() does never return on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, live-sdk

I am trying to manage the Live SDK login in the WP8 app and have problems with this code here:

```
this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient("client Id");
LiveLoginResult loginResult = await this.authClient.InitializeAsync(scopes);
```

This is the code from the sample that Microsoft provides ([Sample](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/blob/master/src/WP8/Samples/LiveLogin/MainPage.xaml.cs)). But authClient.InitializeAsync(scopes) is never returning, I don't get any exception either. MSDN states ([LiveAuthClient.InitializeAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh533669.aspx)) that this method does not return a value on Windows Phone. I would like to use `this.authClient.LoginAsync(scopes)` then in order to manage the login, and can't do it if the client is not initialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I predict that you are calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` further up your call stack, which will [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I explain on my blog).

By default, `await` will capture the "current context" (in this case, likely a UI context), and will use that context to resume the execution of the `async` method. If you block the UI thread by calling `Result` or `Wait` on that task, then the `async` method cannot complete because it's trying to complete on the blocked UI thread.